# How to work withJSON data after calling an AJAX function in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3

With this code:

```
 $("#mybutton").click(function(){
           $.ajax({
                url: '/Member/GetPinPoints/@Model.Id',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            },
            error: function() {

            alert("error");
            }
            });


    return false;
});
```

I am receiving a JSON object that looks like this:

```
[{"Position":1,"Top":182,"Left":20,"Height":73,"Width":90},{"Position":2,"Top":69,"Left":103,"Height":98,"Width":1}]
```

How can I iterate through this data, lets say if i wanted to alert each separate value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain old JavaScript:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    for(var key in data[i]){
        alert(key + " : " + data[i][key]);
    }
}
```

And jQuery:

```
$.each(data, function(index, element){
    $.each(element, function(key, value){
        alert(key + " : " + value);
    });
});
```

You need to iterate in a nested loop since you need to go over all elements in the array and for each array element, go over all properties.

Comment: I'm not following it either. For the data structure in place your answer seems the most valid. + to you.

Comment: @Khepri @naveen Thanks! @naveen I think yours might be because you only access one property (`Position`), a +1 all the same.

Comment: maybe. i just wanted to show the method. was more concerned about the absence of `.d` really :)

Answer (score 1):

The previous examples will work, but they are naive. No good at coding's example will just loop through an array, which isn't very robust.

Let's pretend that you return key/value pairs in your code behind method and you want to be able to pick apart this data to use however you want. You start with this.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static Dictionary<string, string> EditPromo(int promoId)
    {
        using (var db = new DataContext())
        {
            var q = db.Promos.Where(x => x.promoID == promoId).Select(x => x).Single();

            return new Dictionary<string, string>()
                       {
                           {"code", q.code},
                           {"label", q.label},
                           {"expiredate", string.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", q.expireDate)}
                       };
        }
    }
```

Now we can access it via jQuery Ajax like so:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Manager/mPromo/Promo.aspx/EditPromo",
        context: $("#editPromo"),
        data: "{promoId:'" + promoid + "'}",
        success: function (msg)
        {
            var resp = msg.d;
            $("h1:first", this).text("Edit " + resp.code);
            $("input#txtDate", this).val(resp.expiredate);
        }
    });
```

Notice how I created a variable to hold msg.d, called resp. I can then use resp.ReturnedDictionaryKey. Above I used used code and expiredate. I can use them however I please.

Comment: to be fair..anthony did ask for the case of 'if I want to alert each separate value'

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Member/GetPinPoints/@Model.Id',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data) {
            //asp.net 3.5 plus wraps the return into a .d property
            var msg = data.hasOwnProperty("d") ? data.d : data;
            for(var i=0; i < msg.length; i++){
              alert(msg[i].Position);  
            }
        },
        error: function() {

        alert("error");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```